# Help me identify a book - possibly cyberpunk - morse code in raindrops

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

Someone on a forum I frequent once posted an excerpt from what I presume was a book, I don't remember whether they ever quoted the title, but if they did, it's long passed from my memory. I was hoping the folks here could help me work out what it was, as the short passage was atmospheric enough for me to want to read it. I think it had perhaps a sort of cyberpunk vibe.

It sounded like an introduction, either at the start of the book or at the start of a chapter. It describes a man, probably the/a protagonist walking in the rain, thinking to himself before noting that the cadence of the raindrops on his back form a pattern - which he recognises as Morse code.

I'm afraid that's all I remember - it was a short excerpt.

Comment: Hi; I've edited your title to be more descriptive which may help it attract more answers.  It may be a short excerpt but it's a very striking image.

Comment: Vague memory of a story where the main character was in some type of AR/fugue state/dream/coma but didn't know it. Things in his environment start trying to communicate with him. Turns out to be his friends/doctors/coworkers/experimenters trying to talk to him, but the rules of the whatever-it-is integrate the message into the illusion. Sound familiar?

Comment: @ImaginaryEvents not sure, but sounds quite likely. There wasn't a lot of detail in the part that I remember

Comment: When did you encounter this excerpt? What is your best guess when the story was written? Was the forum where you read the piece specialized, such as a gaming forum?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the following:

> "*The raindrops beat gently against his back for what must have been
>   several minutes before he noticed the strange pattern to them*.
>
> ***Morse
>   Code**."*

Several quotes indicate that this is from "The Senator" by Keiko Takemori; Page 216 in the sourcebook of "[Nobilis: A game of Sovereign Powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nobilis)"

Comment: Pretty sure that's it. Awesome - thanks!

Typical that it's not in any way mainstream literature, as I originally saw it on the wargaming forum [Warseer.com](http://www.warseer.com) or possibly its predecessor Portent.net (long offline)

Comment: @Ghryswald. What an excellent fine. Well done!